# Include function to generate TIFF files from .AVI

Tags: matlab, tiff, avi

I am trying to make a function that takes in a movie (.AVI) and produce series of images (.TIF).

I know that I can use this in the command line:

```
obj = VideoReader('movie.m');
vid = read(obj);
frames = obj.NumberOfFrames;
for x = 1 : frames
    imwrite(vid(:,:,:,x),strcat('frame-',num2str(x),'.tif'));
end
```

How do I make it into a function that inputs a movie and generate a series of tif images?

For example, I have a function that, when executed, generates "movie.avi" into the current folder. I want a function avitotif(movie.avi), that takes movie.avi and make series of tif images.

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand your question, what are you trying to change? Do you want to read an avi while it is written?

Comment: @Daniel I want to create a function that inputs a avi file directory and produces series of tif images. 

For example, I have a function makemovie(x,y), that takes in x and y coordinates of a particle with time, and makes a movie of the moving particle. Running this function will give me a movie saved in the current folder. I want another function that takes that movie and make series of tif images in the same folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to do if you want to convert this into a function:

1. Wrap this code with a function header and specify one parameter for the input: The path of where the video is being stored.  Let's call this input `pathToMovie`.
2. Change the first line of the code after the function header so that it takes in a string from the input.

When you're done, save this file as `avitotif.m`, set your working directory to be where this file is located, then run `avitotif('movie.avi');` assuming that the AVI file is also in the same directory.

Here is what the code will look like:

```
function [] = avitotif(pathToMovie)
obj = VideoReader(pathToMovie);
vid = read(obj);
frames = obj.NumberOfFrames;
for x = 1 : frames
    imwrite(vid(:,:,:,x),strcat('frame-',num2str(x),'.tif'));
end
```

Now go ahead and call `avitotif('movie.avi');`

Comment: @user3590969: Took you long enough eh!?  Just kidding.  Thank you for accepting my answer :)

Comment: sorry! Thanks again! Just one more question, if you don't mind. In the path to movie, if it is simply the current working folder, how do I write it? is it just 'pwd'?
Thanks once again

Comment: If it's the current working directory, you don't need to do `pwd`.  Relative filenames assume the current working directory already.  As such you don't need to specify it.  If you did `avitotif('movie.avi');`, this looks for `movie.avi` in the current working directory already.  However, FWIW, yes, the command is `pwd` to get the current working directory